# Switching to another Schengen country for my studies: Do I need another visa?

Tags: student-visa

I am an Indian student studying in Italy on an Italian long-term student visa (multiple entry). I recently received an admission from a German university and wish to migrate to Germany. Can I move to Germany from Italy without applying for German visa?

Comment: You certainly cannot live and study in Germany on your Italian visa. Best case (depending on your citizenship and – future – status) is being able to move to Germany and apply for a residence permit there. But in your case I think you need to apply for a Germany visa at the relevant German consulate in Italy.

Comment: Incidentally, your Italian visa isn't really a Schengen visa (it's a national visa, issued under different rules than Schengen short stay visas).

Comment: The Schengen scheme provides for cross-honoring visas only for short visits and transits. Long stay visas are issued according to national law, and they authorize a long stay only in the country issuing the visa. But because this is about long stay visas, this is a question for [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 3):

You are definitely not allowed to study for more than 90 days (or otherwise reside) in Germany on your Italian visa. It would sometimes be possible to enter the country using that visa and to [apply directly for a residence permit](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6517/switch-from-schengen-visa-to-a-student-visa-in-germany), thus saving some time, but it does not appear to be the case for you, as an Indian citizen coming to study in Germany.

Consequently, **you need to apply for a German visa outside of the country**. However, you do not necessarily need to do that in your country of origin/citizenship. Consulates generally serve people *residing* in the relevant area and it is definitely possible to apply for a German visa in Italy or [elsewhere in the EU](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6492/applying-for-a-student-visa-in-germany-from-netherlands-as-a-non-eu-citizen). You will need to check with the German consulate what they require to establish that you are a resident but I assume that a long-stay visa should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Italian D visa, you are allowed to travel to Germany as if you had a Schengen C multiple-entry visa. That means you can only stay 90 days out of every 180 days, you cannot take a job there, etc. This will not be enough to become a student in Germany.

- You will probably be unable to enroll at the university without residency in Germany.
- It will be difficult to attend all necessary classes, exams, and meetings in the 90/180 rule. It might be possible if you commute every weekend.
- You will not be able to rent a normal flat from a *reputable* landlord. Hotels or tourist housing will be more expensive on the long run. Also, you will be required to register your primary place of residence with the municipal authorities. That makes dodging the 90/180 rule difficult.

Comment: In other words, the answer to "Do I need another visa?" is *yes,* and the answer to "Can I move to Germany from Italy without applying for German visa?" is *no.*

Comment: @phoog, he can "go" to Germany on the Italian visa and look at the town, make *some* arrangements, but he cannot "move" there. The difference between the two things may be hard to draw.

Comment: Not sure this really addresses the question. There are people (e.g. American citizens) and situations (e.g. spouses of EU citizen) where entering Germany under short-stay rules (with or without visa, as applicable) and applying directly for a residence card/permit is possible (no special visa needed). Question is whether this is the case for an Indian citizen seeking a student visa.

Comment: @Gala, as an Italian resident he can enter Germany under the 90/180 rule. And he would apply for any other visa from his place of residence, i.e. Italy.

Comment: @o.m. That's not true (or at least beside the point), there are multiple situations in which you can apply for a residence permit directly from Germany, without the need for any other visa. Question is whether that's the case here. That's why I wrote that you did not address the question (you apparently do not even understand where the issues really lie, the 90/180 rule is just the beginning of it and pontificating on it is not useful). In the meantime, I wrote an answer with links and references you can use to verify all this and educate yourself.

Comment: @Gala, the poster asked if he can move to Germany on his Italian visa without applying for a German one. *Yes*, he can come temporarily, but he needs a visa if he wants to stay for more than 90 days.

Comment: @o.m. Probably and I explained why in my answer. Others (e.g. US citizens) might not. You haven't even stated that he needs to apply for a visa, let alone explained why, instead commenting on mostly irrelevant stuff about the short-stay rules.